# Cannot push back a string into a vector of strings c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program to separate a single line into a vector of strings separated by the blank spaces in said line, so turn:

```
foo bar
```

into

```
["foo", "bar"]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
string command;
string command_temp;
vector<string> command_seperated;

std::cin >> command;

for (int i = 0; i < command.length(); i++){
    if (isspace(command[i])){
        cout << "blankspace" << endl;            command_seperated.push_back(command_temp);
        command_temp.clear();
    }

    command_temp.push_back(command[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < command_temp.size(); i++){
        cout << command_temp[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < command_seperated.size(); i++){
    cout << command_seperated[i] << endl;
}
```

But, if I input `"foo bar"` when prompted, this just returns:

```
foo bar
f
fo
foo

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 2.596 s
Press any key to continue
```

I assume the reason the last `for` loop isn't printing anything is that there's nothing in it and the `push_back` to `command_seperated` isn't working. I have no idea why.

I also don't know why the entire program seems to just stop working after the first blank space.

Using this to refresh my rudimentary C++ skills, so I would appreciate an explanation of why I'm wrong, rather than a more elegant alternative solution.

Comment: The reasons can easily be discovered by stepping through the code with a debugger, did you try that?

Comment: `std::cin >> command` stops when it encounters whitespace. Perhaps you want `std::getline` instead of `>>`?

Comment: Yep, what @RetiredNinja said about ```cin``` is true. I think the code works otherwise. Maybe also put a ```continue;``` in the ```isspace``` conditional, so it doesn't add the space to ```command_temp```.

Comment: comment comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is normal behavior of `operator>>`, which is used for reading [*formatted input*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction).  It skips leading whitespace (if the `skipws` flag is enabled on the stream, which it normally is), then reads until EOF or whitespace is encountered.  So, in your example, `std::cin >> command` receives only `foo` even though you entered `foo bar`.  If you invoked `std::cin >> command` a 2nd time, you would receive `bar`.

To read a string that contains whitespace in it, use `std::getline()` instead:

```cpp
std::getline(std::cin, command);
```

It does not skip leading whitespace, and reads until EOF or a linebreak (ie, from typing <kbd>Enter</kbd>) is encountered.

That being said, the parsing code you have shown can be greatly simplified if you use a `std::istringstream` with `operator>>` to parse the `command`, eg:

```cpp
std::string command, token;
std::vector<std::string> command_seperated;

std::getline(std::cin, command);

std::istringstream iss(command);
while (iss >> token) {
    command_seperated.push_back(token);
}

for (const auto &str : command_seperated){
    cout << str << endl;
}
```